# Static and dynamic type of Set of items which implement an interface

Tags: java, types, interface

I have an interface "workers" and a class that implements it calls "teachers".

in another class, my constructor receives an argument: Set < teachers> teachers
I would like to pass this argument to a super constructor which receives an argument from type: Set < workers>. 
how can I do it?

**this compiles:** workers `blabla=new teachers(1,"blabla");`

**this doesn't:** Set `< workers> set2=new HashSet< teachers>();`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please read (and follow) the
[Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: Set<? extends Worker> = new HashSet<Teacher>();

Comment: thanks! can u please explain this synax? it worked as well but i dont understand it: (What is going on in the set< ?>part)
 Set < CrewMember> set1=(Set< CrewMember>)(Set< ?>)crewMembers;

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `Set<Teachers>` to a `Set<Workers>` using:

```
Set<Workers> set2 = new HashSet<Workers>(setOfTeachers);
```

but note that this will allow you to add any type of workers to that `Set` (i.e. not just `Teachers`.